# Jqueryui slider not working - No errors thrown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery 1.8.2 and jqueryui 1.8.2. 
Simple div.

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

and simple js:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider();
```

I was able to get this to work on jsfiddle.

but doesnt work within my joomla project.

I was suspecting multiple jquery instances. I checked for error in F12 --> console. There were no errors.

And still my div just stays like this:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

nothing gets added to it.

if from the console i execute. `$( "#slider" ).slider();` still nothing happens. 
If i execute `$( "#slider" ).datepicker()` a datepicker nicely gets added.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Is the page loaded when you run `$( "#slider" ).slider();` ?

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: Yes page is loaded. After all controls are loaded i go to F12 --> Console and i run $( "#slider" ).slider(); No change to the original div tag. and no errors reported on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Happened to me before. I remember, after 2 hours of research and wasting time, I found out that jsfiddle uses jQuery UI.css automatically, without mentioning about it at all. (funny but true)

simply add this to your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Css file is in place. Still doesnt work. The div is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem found. was using an artisteer template which was also doing some stuff with the slider class. So that was preventing jqueryui to work. thanks guys.

Just wondering if there was smarter way to figure out that there was another piece of js acting on the same class.